# Add a Header to BaseMapGallery Widget added in ExpandWidget ArcGIS Javascript API 4.1

Tags: basemap, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I want to add a Header in the BaseMapGallery Widget. I have added the BaseMapGallery widget in my ExpandWidget as content. How can I now add some text to the BaseMapGallery widget (e.g. instructions) and a title bar?

Here is my code:

```
var basemapGallery = new BasemapGallery({
    view: view,
    source: [
          // Basemap.fromId("streets-navigation-vector"),
          // Basemap.fromId("satellite"),
          Basemap.fromId("hybrid"),
          Basemap.fromId("dark-gray-vector"),
          Basemap.fromId("osm"),
          Basemap.fromId("gray-vector"),
        ]
}, "basemapGallery");
    var bgExpand2 = new Expand({
     view: view,
     content: basemapGallery
      });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of sending the `basemapGallery` directly into your `Expand` (as the `content` property), instead create your own DOM Node (I'll call this the "wrapper") that has 2 child DOM Nodes: a holder for the instructions, and then a holder of the widget. After you've done all that, send the "wrapper" into your Expand widget. I've added the notable code below, and a [full example demo is here](https://codepen.io/gavinr/pen/GPXLey?editors=0010).

```
// Create a "wrapper" div that contains 2 divs: our instructions, and 
// the div that we will put the Basemap Gallery into. Then send the 
// "wrapper div" in when we create the "Expand"
var wrapper = document.createElement("div");

var instructions = document.createElement("div");
instructions.innerHTML = "Please select a basemap:";
instructions.style.padding = "5px";

var widgetContainer = document.createElement("div");

// add the two divs to the "wrapper"
wrapper.appendChild(instructions);
wrapper.appendChild(widgetContainer);

// send the "widgetContainer" in as the container of the widget
var basemapGallery = new BasemapGallery({
  view: view,
  container: widgetContainer
});

// send the "wrapper" in as the "content" of the "Expand" widget.
var expand = new Expand({
  expandIconClass: "esri-icon-layer-list",
  view: view,
  content: wrapper
});
view.ui.add(expand, "top-right");
```